# HOw can i change the image when we click on the div to open other opened div should close

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
## html ##

<span class="disp">
     <a href="javascript:void(null);" onClick="toggleView('faq1');">
      <img src="cl-bt.gif" id="faq1img" />Estoy interesado en una propiedad</a>
    </span>
<div id="faq1" class="est">Comuníquese directamente con el anunciante usando el formulario <b>"Solicitar más Información"</b> del anuncio que le interesa.
</div>
<span class="disp">
      <a href="javascript:void(null);" onClick="toggleView('faq2');"/>
       <img src=cl-bt.gif" id="faq2img" />Quiero vender o alquilar mi propiedad</a>
     </span>
<div id="faq2" class="est">Anúnciese Gratis.
    <a href="#" style="color:#EF6000; font-weight:bold">Click aquí</a>
</div>
<span class="disp">
     <a href="javascript:void(null);" onClick="toggleView('faq22');">
      <img src="cl-bt.gif" id="faq22img" />¿Como puedo destacar mi anuncio?
     </a>
    </span>
<div id="faq22" class="est">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:#EF6000; font-weight:bold">M&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n sobre Anuncios Destacados
     </a>
</div>

## javascript ##  

function toggleView(id) {
    if ($('#' + id).css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#' + id + 'img').attr('src', 'cl-bt.gif');
        $('#' + id).show();
        $(".est").not($('#' + id)).hide();
        not($('#' + id + 'img')).attr('src', 'cl-rt.gif').show();

    } else {
        $('#' + id + 'img').attr('src', 'cl-rt.gif');
        $('#' + id).hide();

    }

    return true;
}
```

### CSS

```
.disp{ display:block; clear:both; margin-bottom:5px;}
.est
{
  display:block; 
  border:1px dotted #000; 
  background:#FFF; 
  padding:5px; 
  clear:both; 
  margin-bottom:5px;
 }
```

I am using above code to display a div with down arrow(cl-bt.png) when it is opened.When we click on other div the opend div should close and image should change to right arrow(cl-rt.png).But its only closing the div its not changing the image please help me in this

Comment: What is `not(` for before `$('#'+id+'img')).attr('src','cl-rt.gif').show();`?

Comment: it will display right arrow(cl-rt) other than current id But i don't is it aright way of using it or not?